# log4net: write to event log on server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, log4net

My application uses:

- .NET 4
- MVC 3
- Windows Server 2008 R2

I use `log4net` to write to a logs on event log.
My configuration file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <param name="LogName" value="SomeLogName"/>
      <param name="ApplicationName" value="MyAppName"/>
      <some settings for log4net...>
    </appender>
  <log4net>
</configuration>
```

It works well when I run it on my computer (localhost).
But I can not write to event log on server.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the apppool user has full control over the logging directory. He has to have create and update rights.

Enable internal debugging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Or:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ...
</configuration>
```

The C:\tmp\ dir has to excits and you should give the apppool user full control on the directory.